# ¿Cómo posicionar etiquetas en la base de un gráfico de cajas con geom_text de ggplot?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, intellij-idea

Tengo éste código:

```
ggplot(data = Datos_Final, aes(x = Sex, y = Punt_Total)) +
  geom_violin(aes(color=Grupo),fill=NA, alpha = 0.2, show.legend = F, linetype="dotted" )+
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(fill=Grupo, color=Grupo), alpha=0.5, show.legend = F, width=0.5)+
  geom_point(aes(color = Grupo),position = position_jitter(seed = 23, width = 0.2, height = 0), size = 5, show.legend = F, alpha=0.6)+
  geom_point(stat = "summary", fun="mean", shape=15, size=5)+
  labs(y = "Rendimiento", x = "Grupo")+
  geom_text(stat = "summary", fun="mean", aes(label=round(..y..,2)), nudge_y = 1)+
  geom_text(stat = "summary", fun="length", aes(label=..y..))+
  facet_grid(.~Grupo, labeller = labeller(Grupo = c("Control"="Tradicional\n (Control)", "Experimental"="Digital\n (Experimental)")))+
  theme_apa7OS()+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 16, color = "#595959"))
```

me arroja el siguiente gráfico:

[image: RendimientoPorSexo]

Como se ve, los valores 5, 10, 6 y 8 corresponden a la cantidad de elementos por cada grupo o cantidad de observaciones, lo que quiero es que estos valores se situen en la posición 1 del eje vertical "y", he intentado de todas las formas que sé y no me ha resultado.

He intentado añadiendo el valor de la posición en el eje "y" de esta forma, con este código, pero no resulta:

```
geom_text(stat = "summary", fun="length", aes(label=..y.., y=1))+
```

He intentado agregando fuera de aes() pero tampoco resulta:

```
geom_text(stat = "summary", fun="length", aes(label=..y..), y=1)+
```

Cuando utilizo el parámetro position, solo logro desplazar una determinada cantidad de puntos por arriba o por debajo del punto de referencia con lo cual queda uno mas arriba que otro, pero lo que quiero es que todos los valores se situen en la base, en el punto 1 del eje vertical "y".

Se los agradeceria enormemente.

Comment: Prueba modificar `y` pero dentro de `aes()`: `geom_text(stat = "summary", fun="length", aes(label=..y.., y=1))+`

Comment: Ya intenté esa opcion, pero no hace ningun cambio agregar y=1 dentro de aes()

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer eventualmente es:

```
  geom_text(stat = "summary", 
            fun="length",
            vjust = -2,
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0),
            aes(label=..y..))
```

Con `position_stack(vjust = 0)` ajustamos a 0 las diferencias de la posición `y` de cada grupo, o sea, las alineamos.  Luego con `vjust = -2` ajustamos la posición donde se muestran.